# An Issue with Importing Files with Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I have saved multiple figures by using pickle.dump on a computer device. Now, I want to load the files on my laptop using pickle.load. I wrote the following code
for filename in filenames:

```
    with open( path + filename + '.pkl','rb' ) as file:
              linedata = pickle.load(file)
    # plt.close()
    ax = plt.gca()
    
    for m in range( len(M) ):
        line = ax.lines[ m ]
        keyname = filename + '_M=' +  str( M[m] )
        outdict[keyname] = [ line.get_xdata(line), line.get_ydata(line), Linestyle[cnt], Labels[cnt]+ r'$~M={}$'.format(M[m]), Colors[m] ]
        plt.close()
    cnt+=1
```

However, the following error is raised:

AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_picklable_subplot_class_constructor' on <module 'matplotlib.axes._subplots' from '/Users/saleh/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py'>

I would appreciate if anyone can solve my problem.

Comment: In my experience, pickle should only be used on a single machine for relatively temporary data.  The problem with using pickle to pass data between environments is that the generated data is very fragile.  It relies on the environment that is reading the pickle file being very similar to the environment that wrote the file.  Even updating Python or some individual package on your own machine can break a pickle file.  I can't be sure that this is your problem given only what you've shown, but given that you're reading and writing on different machines, it's quite likely.

Comment: Can you read the file using this code on the same machine that wrote the file?  If you can, then it has to be what I said above. The answer then, if you must use pickle, would be to build and run your code in two virtual environments that you've built using the same `requirements.txt` file, one that specifies exact versions of the packages it mentions.  Also start with the same Python version on each machine, or as close as possible.  If you run in these environments on both sides, you're more likely to not have a problem.  Other differences, like Mac vs Win, can still cause trouble.

Comment: I've run on the same machine and it worked. Thank you.